# How to display jupyter notebook or apache zeppelin in my application ?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, apache-zeppelin, bigdata

I have a application WEB (laravel) I using Postgresql to Transaction and ACID data, mongodb to many king of informations ans apache spark to processes and get insight from this.
But, I need produces dashbord from this app and put it into mys application analys área.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can utilize.

1. using **Paragraph REST API**: fetch paragraph results using AJAX and display it in your application.

   - http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#get-a-paragraph-information
2. Publishing paragraphs and get the permalinks, then embed them in your application.

   - http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/manual/publish.html#embed-the-paragraph-to-your-website
3. Use the report mode: Report mode is remove all buttons, things unrelated and **only keep useful results**

   (This is not the exact solution what you want but you might be interested)

   - http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/explorezeppelinui.html#note-toolbar

[image]

You might get more ideas from Zeppelin Documentation.

- http://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0-SNAPSHOT/